# vue-owl-carousel is not working with v-for

Tags: vuejs2, carousel

I am using vue-owl-carousel and each item are being populated using v-for.

```
<carousel>
  <div v-for="index in myArr">
    {{index}}
  </div>
</carousel>

...

<script>
 export default {
   name: "myComponent",
   data: {
     myArr: []
   },
   mounted: {
     for(let i = 1; i < 6; i++) myArr.push(i);
   }
 }
</script>
```

But it is not working and it is just working with static elements like this one.

```
<carousel>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</carousel>
```

How should I manage this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

Add `method` for your Array initialization, then go for `mounted` hook to initialize pushedArray when component is ready.

My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jwaLsnk4/1/

Note, this only works for normal Array without Objects. Cheers

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jwaLsnk4/1/ 

Updated original reply as well.